# Publish a pubsub message in flutter/dart

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to publish a pub/sub message in my flutter application like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/pubsub//v1.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';

const _SCOPES = const [PubsubApi.PubsubScope];

class Activities extends StatefulWidget {
  Activities();

  @override
  _Activities createState() => _Activities();
}

final _credentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(r'''
{
  "type": "service_account",
  ...
}
''');

class _Activities extends State<Activities> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: new MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              debugPrint("trying to publish a message...");
              clientViaServiceAccount(_credentials, _SCOPES)
                .then((http_client) {
                  var pubSubClient = new PubsubApi(http_client);
                  Map<String, dynamic> message = new Map<String, dynamic>();
                  message["data"] = Map<String, dynamic>();
                  message["data"]["type"] = "foo";
                  message["data"]["senderId"] = "bar";

                  pubSubClient.projects.topics
                      .publish(new PublishRequest.fromJson(message), "projects/myProject/topics/events")
                      .then((publishResponse) {
                    debugPrint(publishResponse.toString());
                  }).catchError((e,m){
                    debugPrint(e.toString());
                  });
                })
                .catchError((e,m) {
                  debugPrint(e.toString());
                });
            },
            child: new Text("Publish message"),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

But in the logs I get the following error message:

`I/flutter ( 5281): DetailedApiRequestError(status: 400, message: The value for 0 is too small. You passed message_count in the request, but the minimum value is 1.)`

I googled this message but did not found anything. I think my message structure is maybe wrong, but maybe it's something else ? Don't wanna lose too much time on it...

Comment: Does "new PublishRequest" belong to this [AWS-Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/model/PublishRequest.html) class or which exactly library are you using?
Have you tried to use this [Google libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries)?

Comment: @Temu I'm using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis, I'm using google pubsub, I was not aware there was an equivalent in amazon (?)

Comment: I see, I though "dart" was just another library and not another language!!!! Sorry for the oversight!

Comment: @GwydionFR I added flutter package ```googleapis``` but when i tried to ```import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';``` getting error as URI doesn't exists. I already tired flutter clean, restart IntelliJ.

Comment: I dont work with flutter I cant help but the path does not seem to have change since. Look at this https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, for those who wonder, here is what I have come up with:

```
var messages = {
    'messages': [
                  {
                    'data': base64Encode(utf8.encode('{"foo": "bar"}')),
                  },
                ]
              };

pubSubClient.projects.topics
                  .publish(new PublishRequest.fromJson(messages), "your topic")
                  .then((publishResponse) {
                debugPrint(publishResponse.toString());
              }).catchError((e,m){
                debugPrint(e.toString());
              });
```

Maybe someone should write an article on it, this was not very clear and I had to try different things and also read the source from the pubsub client library...

Comment: Do we need to follow certain steps for connection to the Google cloud pub-sub before publishing message?

Comment: Yes, its in the sample code: `clientViaServiceAccount(_credentials, _SCOPES)`. The service account should be downloaded from Google Cloud Platform UI or via the gcloud cli. Its a json file containing authent stuff

Comment: I try this and I get this error `DetailedApiRequestError(status: 404, message: No error details. HTTP status was: 404.)`

Answer (score 0):

Use [gcloud: ^0.7.3](https://pub.dev/packages/gcloud#cloud-pubsub) package.

Use the below code to establish a connection.

```
import 'package:gcloud/pubsub.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/pubsub/v1.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';

// Read the service account credentials from the file.
var jsonCredentials = new File('my-project.json').readAsStringSync();
var credentials = new auth.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(jsonCredentials);


var client = await auth.clientViaServiceAccount(credentials, scopes);
var pubsub = new PubSub(client, 'my-project');
```

For the Publish and Subscribe refer to [this](https://pub.dev/packages/gcloud#cloud-pubsub) section of the readme.

Comment: can you explain how do i get and where to store my-project file in flutter?